# Why does my Jasmine spec think my Angular module is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Why does my Jasmine spec think my Angular module is undefined?  I've added a line of code setting a boolean to true below the actual module code, and then I console.log it from within the spec, and it indicates true.  I've also tried changing the module so it is not an ultra-scope (my term) or IIFE, but that has no effect.  The gist of the error message is `Expected undefined to equal <jasmine.any(Object)>.`

Spec runner:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Angular Spec Runner</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/boot.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/angular-mocks.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../services/common/common.js"></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="specs/commonSpec.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Angular module:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var commonModule = angular.module('common', []);

    commonModule.factory('common',
        ['$q', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '$location', 'logger', 'toaster', common]);

    function common($q, $rootScope, $timeout, $location, logger, toaster) {
        var throttles = {};

        var service = {
            isPhoneNumber: isPhoneNumber
        };

        return service;

        function isPhoneNumber(phoneStr) {
            phoneStr = phoneStr.replace(/\D/g, ''); //strips parens, dots, dashes, etc.
            return phoneStr.length === 10
                    && parseInt(phoneStr, 10) >= 2000000000 //area code can't start with 0 or 1
                    && parseInt(phoneStr.slice(-7), 10) >= 2000000; //exchange can't start with 0 or 1
        };
    }
})();

window.commonModuleLoaded = true;
```

Spec:

```
'use strict';

describe('common', function () {
    var common;

    beforeEach(module('common'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_common_) {
        common = _common_;
    }));

    console.log('window.commonModuleLoaded :' + window.commonModuleLoaded);

    it('is an object', function () {
        expect(common).toEqual(jasmine.any(Object));
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'be' of undefined

clearly says that there's something wrong in this piece of code

```
expect(common).to.be.a('Object');
```

and not in `common` service.

This results from the fact that the code was pasted from the spec that uses Chai framework for assertions and not Jasmine, those two have different APIs. Chai syntax uses dot separators, Jasmine methods are camel-cased.

Jasmine has simple API that is covered [on a single page](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html), the spec should become

```
expect(common).toEqual(jasmine.any(Object));
```

The only case when `common` variable may become `undefined` silently is when  `common` service was accidentally overridden to return `undefined`. In any other case injection error would be thrown.

The injection error in the spec

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: loggerProvider <- logger <- common http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$injector/unpr?p0=loggerProvider%20%3C-%20logger%20%3C-%20common

results from the fact that third-party module files weren't loaded and the modules weren't loaded in `common` module.

A way to fix this is to load dependencies in spec:

```
beforeEach(module('loggerModuleName', 'toasterModuleName', 'common'));
```

But the preferable way is to fix `common` module itself, because a module should explicitly state its dependencies, not just rely on parent module to load them:

```
var commonModule = angular.module('common', ['loggerModuleName', 'toasterModuleName']);
```

Comment: Ok my bad.  But `common` still comes out of the second `beforeEach` block as undefined.  In fact I don't even think the block is being executed, I've tried putting `debugger` and/or `console.log` within that block, and the statements don't execute.  Is the second `beforeEach` even valid as written?  The jasmine API may be simple to you but again, this is my first exposure to it, and I'm trying to integrate it with Angular to boot.  Any further direction is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, second `beforeEach` is proper. If there is something wrong with service injection, it won't not just fail silently but will throw a specific error, so the problem can be easily traced. If there are no errors, `common` should be equal to actual service value. The code is truncated and doesn't show what `common` factory returns. If it doesn't return anything, it will be `undefined`.

Comment: There's a `return service` statement, and I've been using this for two months without issue.  Still `common` comes out undefined after the second `beforeEach` :(  After one line of code to the one you sent me, I got a different error -- see above in my modifications.

Comment: `expect` still should be inside `it` block, like it was in original code. If that's what you've tried before, this is the reason why `beforeEach` block didn't run - it runs *before each* `it` spec. And doesn't run if there is none. I see no valid reasons why `common` can be undefined here.  I would suggest to replicate the problem on Plunker if you still have problems with it. Also notice that `angular-mocks` should be loaded after Jasmine and Angular.

Comment: I think I have the ordering of the loading of the various files correct.  I put the `expect` back inside the `it` and now get this error: "Expected undefined to equal <jasmine.any(Object)>."  `common` is coming out of the second `beforeEach` as undefined.  I think I'm going to modify my question to include an entire service where I strip out everything except one method.  Thanks for your continued willingness to help.

Comment: You're welcome. A reproducible fiddle/plunker would be more helpful, because the listed code is ok and cannot explain the behaviour. You may also inject a service right into the spec with `it('...', inject(function (common) { expect(common)... }))`, but it is essentially the same as the above. At this point the only good explanation is that `common` service was accidentally overridden to return `undefined` or wrong file was included. In any other case injection error would be thrown and  `expect` line would be unreachable. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I'm going back to square one, and maybe try with one of my controllers instead

Comment: I upvoted this although it no longer applies to the question as currently written

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. [This will result in having the spec passing](http://plnkr.co/edit/MxU7yIaAJDkx2eh27Uxa?p=preview) when missing third-party services are commented. And [it throws an injector error](http://plnkr.co/edit/p30GwU9c42qwzWGeEAql?p=preview) when they are not commented. And [it never reaches `expect`](http://plnkr.co/edit/PYtNUAEoCETLQdXtUGSb?p=preview) when `common` is injected into the spec itself. This corresponds to previous comments. Have you missed the error in your testing rig?

Comment: Hi Estus thanks for commenting.  Please remember I am completely new to Jasmine, so I'm not quite following your explanations.  Do you want to edit this answer with this comment as the foundation and any extra detail you think I need?  Apparently I need some serious hand holding to get off the ground on this one, but hopefully once I have it down it will be much simpler moving forward.

Comment: I've updated the answer to match the changes in the question. The problem applies to Angular DI rather than Jasmine or testing.