# When testing Angular services with Jasmine, is the inclusion order of scripts causing this unknown provider error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have an Angular service that is including two other modules: `logger` and `toaster`.  logger.js is local and I've included it in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yO4izdDTgllRbI26lyHT?p=preview).  As for toaster it is a third party library, and within the plunker, index.html is including it as a script tag.

This is my first attempt at testing with Jasmine, and I've trimmed things down to be concise.  At first I couldn't get the tests to pass due to an injector error related to the `logger` module.  Finally through trial and error, I noticed that, in index.html, if I loaded logger.js *after* common.js, the error would go away and the tests would pass.

Now I am trying to pass the `toaster` module into the `common` service module, but no matter where I include the reference to toaster.min.js, I get the following error.  When I run this locally instead of as a plunkr, I can verify that toaster.min.js is getting loaded; furthermore by looking at its content, I've verified that it defines a `toaster` module.  So I am kind of at a loss as to what else to try in order to get `toaster` to load properly so I can finish the testing of my `common` service.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: toasterProvider <- toaster <- common
```

If it's not the order of including the modules via their script/src tags, any other help would be appreciated, up to and including forking and modifying the plunker so it runs.

Comment: It has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486014/why-does-my-jasmine-spec-think-my-angular-module-is-undefined). You need to have dependency modules (namely `toaster`) loaded in dependent module (`common`): `angular.module('common', ['toaster'])`. Just follow the answer. It isn't specific to Jasmine or testing, the same thing will happen if you will try to instantiate `common` service in isolation from the application: `angular.injector(['ng', 'common']).get('common')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module can be [successfully used in production and testing](http://plnkr.co/edit/BmHBG8607jyKNfCPWIu5?p=preview) if the dependencies are loaded properly for the module:

```
var commonModule = angular.module('common', ['toaster']);

//runs without error: commonModule.factory('common',['logger', common]);
commonModule.factory('common',['logger', 'toaster', common]);
```

`common` service from `commonModule` module depends on `toaster` service from `toaster` module, hence `commonModule` should load `toaster` module as a dependency.

The same applies to any services that aren't defined in the current module.

Answer (score 2):

you need to inject the following modules first

```
beforeEach(module('toaster'));
```

then

```
 beforeEach(module('common'));
```

Comment: i think this is enough to solve your problem and your fiddle is working